# The tangent map of the exponential map

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, sasaki-metric

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $\exp^M:TM\to M$ denote the exponential map. Its tangent map $T\exp^M$ is a map $TTM\to TM$. The connection on $TM$ induces a canonical metric on $TM$, the Sasaki metric $S$. Denote by $\exp^{TM}$ the exponential map on $(TM,S)$, which is a map $TTM\to TM$.

Question: is there a (simple) relation between $T\exp^M$ and $\exp^{TM}$? Are they equal? If not, are there cases in which they are equal (e.g, spheres)?

Comment: The two maps are closer to being comparable after pre-composing one or the other with the involution of the double tangent bundle. Jan's comment is observing that the two maps take values in involuted tangent spaces.

Comment: I think your question boils down to the issue of if one varies the starting point of a geodesic, this process infinitesimally gives rise to a vector field along the geodesic.  Your question asks if these vector fields are parallel along the geodesic.  Presumably this isn't always true and there will be a relation with the Riemann curvature tensor. It might be something of the form $exp^{TM}-T(exp^M) \circ \iota$ being given in terms of some ODE involving the Riemann curvature tensor along the appropriate geodesic.

Comment: @RyanBudney This question has also been studied. The ODE is called the Jacobi equation and these fields being parallel is equivalent to the manifold in question being flat.

Answer (score 9):

These maps can never be equal unless your manifold has dimension zero.

This has a rather trivial reason. If we look at both of these maps on a neighborhood of $0$ in $T_v T_p M$ for some fixed $v\in T_p M$, we see that $d{\exp^M}$ takes values in a neighborhood of $0$ in $ T_{\exp(v)}M$, while $\exp^{TM}$ takes values near $v$ in $TM$. Since $\exp(v)$ tends to be different in $M$ from the basepoint of $v$, these have no chance of generic equality.

Comment: Notation depends a bit on how you define these things. For me $TM$ is as a set the union of all tangent spaces, so an element of $TM$ is called $v$, while for you $TM$ seems to consist of pairs of a tangent vector and its basepoint.
Either way, $T_v T_p M$ is not the same as $T_v TM$, one is a strict subset of the other. Of course, since we could have just evaluated only a zero to begin with, the two maps can generally agree on neither.

Comment: Oh, you are perfectly right! I edited the answer, that was a slip of my brain.

Comment: thanks for fixing it. I've deleted my comments which are now obsolete.